# How to copy resulting installer

Tags: inno-setup

Using Inno Setup Studio, I need to copy resulting installer to a saved network location.

It could be a Post Compilation Step with something like this:

```
copy /Y /B valueof(OutputDir)+valueof(OutputBaseFilename)+".exe" "\\Server\Path\"
```

But I don't know how to implement valueof().

Comment: It seems that Inno Script Studio does not *post process* that section in teh way as preprocessor does, I mean that it does not expand preprocessor variables there. So I'm out of ideas. Try to ask the author (as it's closed source tool), or create the batch file as I suggested in my (now deleted) answer.

Comment: P.S. for passing parameters, the `[PostCompile]` section contains the `Parameters` parameter (there's so many parameters in this sentence :)

Comment: @TLama This is what I feared (non post processing of PostCompilation). I have a surrounding script but I like to keep my .iss usable independently. Great thanks.

Comment: You can still wait for someone experienced, or simply ask the author, since I don't know nor use this tool. I've been just probing if that section is preprocessed; and my result is that it isn't. However, Inno Setup's preprocessor does not care what section you're in, so it would preprocess even that `[PostCompile]` section. My guess is that the ISS tool removes those pseudo-sections before preprocessing (building), or more likely, that they're added right when you're getting the whole script (but they are hidden from compiler and preprocessor).

Comment: So if you would pass the ISS script to the Inno Setup's preprocessor and that preprocessed script pass to the ISS, it could do what you want. But it's ugly, ugly way, since you would be passing already processed script...

Comment: @TLama I'm already doing some poor man preprocessing: my surrounding script modify my .iss. It's done to update product verion according to external manifest. I can complexify this and also modify OutputDir and OutputBaseFilename by hand. Ugly too but I prefer to rely on only one ugly thing.

Comment: A good alternative to modifying the actual .iss file is often to use an #include and write whatever you'd alter in an external file that's simply included at that point. I've done that for generated file lists in one project.